# CSS SubMenu modification

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive, submenu

Need some CSS help regarding SubMenu creation.
I have this below code for responsive Main Menu which is working fine. I need to create a SubMenu under the main menu. 
For example :- **Menu2** will habe two submenu like **Menu2_SubMenu1** & **Menu2_SubMenu2**.
The color, format and hovering effect will be same like Main menu.

Can you kindly help me out with the CSS for the same. I am messing up with the Submenu CSS code code. Thanks in advance for your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    ul.topnav {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #2D5C88;
      text-align: center;
      /* For fixed header   */
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    ul.topnav li {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    ul.topnav li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-family: 'Verdana', Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    
    ul.topnav li a:hover {
      background-color: #33699b;
    }
    
    ul.topnav li.icon {
      display: none;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
      ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
      ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
      ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="google.com">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.gogle.com">**Menu2**</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.gogle.com/">Menu3</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you add myFunction code

Comment: Hi Hunzaboy, Don't think so. It is a simple HTML pallet where I have modified the CSS code for my Menu. Need to implement the Sub-menu for the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    breakpoint: 768,
    format: "multitoggle"
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #2d5c88;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #2d5c88;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #dddddd;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #dddddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 23px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 23px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #274f75;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 19px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 15px;
  right: 13px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- MenuMaker Plugin -->
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Menus</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 2.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.4</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 3.5</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 1.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 1.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 1.3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 1.4</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 2.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 2.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Settings 3</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 3.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 3.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Settings 4</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 4.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 4.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 4.3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Settings 4.4</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```